# node.js/javascript: Simple Database Query in Node check empty

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a Simple Query in node.js. But i can not handle the error or empty. I have tried:

- isempty, =="", =="undefined"

  ```
  con.query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE secretkey = 
  '"+connection_on_obj.secretkey+"' AND id = 
   '"+connection_on_obj.userid+"' LIMIT 1",

   function (err, result, fields) {

   if(err) {

   console.log("ERROR");

   }else{

    if(result[0].id) {

      console.log("OK");

     }else{

     console.log("NO USER");

     }

   }
  });
  ```

I become in the most cases the error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want check if you got an empty list,just check the size of the array.

```
if (result.length === 0) {
    // "error", no results found.
}
```

Comment: Works not for me :-(. result[0].id.length===0 --- `/sockets/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
                                                                                                           
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Query._callback (/sockets/index.js:75:26)`

Comment: `result.length`, not `result[0].id.length`.

Comment: Works now fine. Thanks